# ¿Cómo juntar dos listas sin que se combinen los elementos en python?

Tags: python, lista

Tengo un pequeño programa que realiza consultas de datos de un API.
Quisiera poder generar una lista de listas (anidada) en la que cada elemento fuera el resultado de la consulta.

Os muestro el código simplificado:

```
f= ["Campo1","Campo2","Campo3","Campo4"]
#Aquí va todo el código de la consulta que lo voy a obviar#
out_1 = [lista[i]]
out_1.append(soup.np.text)
out_1.append(soup.nm.text)

out_2 = [soup.cn.text]
out_2.append(soup.cpo.text)

output = out_1 + out_2
f = f.extend(output)
```

La idea es que el resultado sea:

```
[["Campo1","Campo2","Campo3","Campo4"] , [Resultado1,Resultado2,Resultado3,Resultado4], ...]
```

Sin embargo el resultado es:

```
["Campo1","Campo2","Campo3","Campo4", Resultado1, Resultado2, Resultado3, Resultado4, ...]
```

Comment: No uses `.extend()` sino `.append()`

Answer (score 3):

Si usas `extend`, que es lo mismo que `+`, Python juntará los elementos de las listas:

```
>>> d = [1, 2, 3]
>>> e = [4, 5, 6]
>>> d + e
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

>>> d.extend(e)
>>> d
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Sin embargo, si usas `append()` añadirá cada lista por separado:

```
>>> d = [1, 2, 3]
>>> e = [4, 5, 6]
>>> res = []
>>> res.append(d)
>>> res.append(e)
>>> res
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Que sería lo mismo que hacer `res = [d, e]`.

Comment: He probado con `f =[f, output]` y el resultado sigue siendo el mismo

Comment: Fíjate en el ejemplo en mi respuesta. No puedo replicar tu resultado porque no tengo los dados

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear directamente la lista final a partir de las otras:

```
lista1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lista2 = ['a','b','c']

lista = [lista1, lista2] => [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

`lista` contiene dos elementos, cada uno de ellos una lista.

Answer (score 1):

Un variante sencilla para poder **insertar listas dentro de otra lista** podría ser agregando corchetes:

Datos ejemplo:

```
f= ["Campo1","Campo2","Campo3","Campo4"]
output = ["Campo5","Campo6","Campo7","Campo8"]


f = [f] + [output]
```

Ahora `f` que inicialmente era una [lista] devuelve una [[lista] de listas].

El resultado sera:

```
[["Campo1","Campo2","Campo3","Campo4"],["Campo5","Campo6","Campo7","Campo8"]]
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.